# Inline VF page is showing in record edit mode in Lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, inline-visualforce, app-builder

I have added inline visualforce page in account page layout. It is working properly in classic experience.

In Lightning experience, I have updated the account record page using app builder. I am using " Record Detail" standard component in record page. When I create a new account record, the page does not show any inline VF page. However, when I edit existing account record, it shows me inline VF page in the edit page.

How can I avoid showing this inline VF page in edit page in Lightning Experience?